# Where do you publish information about a vulnerability you have found within android?

Tags: security, browser, google, bugs

I found a small vulnerability within the default web browser, here is the ticket. Submitted last year.

> Issue 42647: Android Web Browser, JavaScript Popup Bug. Tested on 11 Jan 2013.
>   Vulnerability on Android OS 4.1.2 jelly-bean on the samsung galaxy s3, this may also work on other phones.
>
> Loop vulnerability in mobiles default browser.
>
> I also created a method, on how to fix the vulnerability.
>
> Type-Security
>   Priority-Medium
>
> Submitted to: Android https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

E.g. Was this the correct place, to submit, as the bug is still active. Tested on the Sony Xperia M. 05/11/14.

Comment: I'd say so. With the exception of vuls which could be exploited to gain root permissions – those should go to XDA, so they can make a rooting tool ;)

Comment: If I managed to stumble across a vulnerability that could*  modify root, XDA would be the first place to divulge that information. I am one to believe in technology openness.